# I tried to implement user authentication in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, authentication

Tried to implement user authentication, but got stuck
(Tech stack: React, Node, Express, Postgresql)

```
  router.post("/signin", function (req, res) {
    User.find({
      where: {
        name: req.body.username,
      },
    })
      .then((user) => {
        if (!user) {
          return res.status(401).send({
            message: "Authentication failed. User not found.",
          });
        }
        user.comparePassword(req.body.password, (err, isMatch) => {
          if (isMatch && !err) {
            var token = jwt.sign(
              JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)),
              "nodeauthsecret",
              { expiresIn: 86400 * 30 }
            );
            jwt.verify(token, "nodeauthsecret", function (err, data) {
              console.log(err, data);
            });
            res.json({ success: true, token: "JWT " + token });
          } else {
            res.status(401).send({
              success: false,
              msg: "Authentication failed. Wrong password.",
            });
          }
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
  });
```

It returns 500 Error.

I tried testing using Postman but it returns Error. I reviewed the code many times and the logic looks good to me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems to be wrong with the code. Can I see your user model

Comment: Yes, [here](https://gist.github.com/gokhanmelma/95fd7e9b49dd062d5b37d6dba2ec2040) it is.

Comment: I fixed the issue. To retrieve a user from db, I should use `findOne`. `find` is deprecated